# рекурсия ли это ? объясните что тут происходит

Tags: javascript

почему в каждом 0-вом элементе тот же нулевой элемент до бесконечности и вроде рекурсии нету не пойму никак

```js
let arr = ["a", "b"];

arr.push(function() {
  arr.unshift(this)
})
arr[2]();

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: да, он содержит ссылку на самого себя, `.unshift(this)` добавляет ссылку на самого себя в начало массива

Comment: но почему это повторяется бесконечно?

Comment: Если Вы имеете в виду вывод гугл хрома в дебаг - они так реализовали вывод циклической ссылки

Comment: да я про google спасибо гляну про циклическую ссылку

Comment: к слову: местный вывод в лог (в сниппете) по-другому разруливает циклические ссылки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Этот феномен называется "Циклическая ссылка" или "Ссылка на самого себя"

Циклические ссылки в общем случае это не только ссылки на самого себя, но и опосредованные циклические ссылки.

---

Ссылка на самого себя:

```js
let a = {x:1};
a.a = a;
console.log(a)
```

---

Опосредованная циклическая ссылка

```js
let a = {x: 1};
a.a = {x: 2, a};
console.log(a);
```

PS:

Отладчик браузера google chrome, использует "ленивое вычисление" и в момент раскрытия узла, добавляет его содержимое, да это своего рода рекурсия, точнее рекурсия применена для вывода представления циклической ссылки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

могло быть сделано иначе, например как в сниппете тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кстати вопрос появился а что за синтехсис в сниппетах(какой язык используется для написания сниппета)

Comment: HTML + CSS +Javascript